# User Interface with drawables and buttons in Android XML

Tags: android, user-interface, graphics

I want to design a user interface in XML in AndroidStudio. It is a simple interface: Two rows of buttons on the bottom of the screen, and the rest of the screen covered by a Canvas, or anything that I can draw lines and polygons on. I am a novice at specifying UIs in XML. Can anyone help me?

I tried it with a LinearLayout, but it made all the rows the same height, the buttons and the canvas.

Comment: Show what you have already done, add links to tutorials that you have followed. To get the right answer from the community, you will have to show that you have already tried everything that you can.
BTW, there are extremely many tutorials demonstrating what you want. A Google search wil lead you to many more resources than what you may get here.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this using the ConstraintLayout. With it, you are able to place all of your UI components dynamically on the screen. Take a look at [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/9475-constraintlayout-tutorial-for-android-complex-layouts). You can easily convert the LinearLayout to a ConstraintLayout too.